# Is this substitution, a sufficient condition to find the range of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, alternative-proof

I have this function ($x>0$)
$$f (x)=\frac{\sqrt{g (x)}+4 x \left(x^2+1\right) \sin (\pi  x) \cos ((3+\pi ) x)}{x^4+2 x^2+1+\left(4 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cos (2 \pi  x)\right)}$$
where $g(x)=4 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cos (2 \pi  x)-\left(x^2+1\right)^2 \cos (2 (3+\pi ) x)\;$. I want to show that the range of function $f(x)$ for those values of $x$ in which $g(x)=0\;$ is $[-1,1]$.

From $g(x)=0\;$ we have $\;4 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cos (2 \pi  x)=\left(x^2+1\right)^2 \cos (2 (3+\pi ) x)\;$. The LHS is the same as one of the term in denominator of $f$. Then, is it sufficient to substitute this term in $f$ and then check the range? Does this give the range of the function for only those values of $x$ for which $g(x)=0$?  If not, how can I prove that the range of function $f(x)$ for those values of $x$ in which $g(x)=0\;$ is $[-1,1]$?

> P.S. I did this way, but I see that that the range of function for
> some $x_0$ is greater than one, but when I check  $g(x_0)\;$, it is
> not zero!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can substitute like you have done and the range so obtained will only consist values of $f(x)$ for which $g(x)=0$ is satisfied.

Though only substituting the value of $g(x)$ ,like you have done, does not lead to the complete solution...

Here is one way of doing this...
For the eqaution $g(x)=0$, use the identity $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2t$ for both cosines and simplify to get

$$\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\sin((3+\pi)x)} \right)^2$$

Using this alongwith substituting the value as you have mentioned leads to

$$f(x)=\frac{2x\sin(\pi x)}{(x^2+1)\cos((3+\pi )x)}=\frac{2x \sin(\pi x)}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^2-(\sin(\pi x)^2(x^2-1)^2}} $$

Now this indeed lies between $[-1,1]$.

Comment: For the first equality, I just did simple simplifications like putting $g(x)=0$ , writing $x^4+2x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2$,taking that out as the common term in the denominator and then using $1+\cos(2(3+\pi)x)=2\cos^2((3+\pi)x)$ cancelling that $\cos((3+\pi)x)$ from numerator and denominator...Then for the second equality, I used the above relation to solve for $\cos((3+\pi)x)$ by using $\cos^2((3+\pi)x)=1-\sin^2((3+\pi)x)$ and substituted that...

Comment: You should prove it by dividing by $\sin(\pi x)$ from both numerator and denominator and noting that $$(x^2+1)^2\csc^2(\pi x)-(x^2-1)^2\geq (x^2+1)^2-(x^2-1)^2\geq 4x^2$$Can you finish now?